# set picklist values on profile basis

Tags: apex, record-type, record

I created a picklist field on custom object and couple of record types to separate values of picklist field. Than assigned one recordtype to internal users profile
and other to external user's profile. All works good expect when seeing record created by internal user into community, which shows picklist values as per internal user's record  type setting.

Comment: Records don't exist "inside" or "outside" a community. They're all the same data. This sounds like it could be an x-y problem; want to share more information about what the underlying objective is?

Comment: Did you create unique page layouts for each record type and hide the record type field on the community user layout when you did? In doing that, the record type gets set to the default for that profile. You only make records of the the other type visible to users who have profiles that you want to see them & assign the correct page layout to their profile.